# How to remove some elements If it was contains specific values inside recycle view?

Tags: java, android

I have succeeded in making more data download and then put it inside Recycleview and I succeeded in doing that and I used everything well but the problem is that I try to load some elements if they contain a value of 3, for example inside the function Loadmore I tried to make a loop and then I put the value 3 and then delete all the value equal to this number 
but I have not succeeded so far please help and put the appropriate code

```
// my code 
public class Page_6Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    TextView th, tm, tt, tapm;
    Spinner spin_h, spin_m, spin_apm, spin_day;
    RadioButton radioReject,radioAccipt ;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    Button buttonDialogReject,buttonDialogAccipt;
    Dialog dialog;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Customer> customers;
    CustomerAdapter adapter;
    View rootView;
    String TAG = "MainActivity - ";
    Context context;
    API api;
    Boolean acceptOrNo = true;
    Context c = null;
    String lock;
    public int[] userLock;

    public static Page_6Fragment instance;

    public static Page_6Fragment newInstance() {

        Page_6Fragment fragment = new Page_6Fragment();

        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customer, container, false);
        this.context = getActivity();
        this.instance = this;
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        customers = new ArrayList<>();
         // Postion is index item inside recycleview =
        adapter = new CustomerAdapter(Page_6Fragment.this,customers){
            @Override
            public void buttonClickEvent(int position){
              // Toast.makeText(context,"posIs: "+position+" userLock.len= "+userLock.length,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 //showDialog(context,customers.get(position).user_id , Integer.parseInt(customers.get(position).id));
                 //---- condithion 1
                if(customers.get(position).status ==0){
                   showDialog(context,customers.get(position).user_id , Integer.parseInt(customers.get(position).id));
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context,"تم الرد على هذا المستخدم مسبقا", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        };


        adapter.setLoadMoreListener(new CustomerAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int index = customers.size();
                        loadMore(index);
                    }
                });
                //Calling loadMore function in Runnable to fix the
                // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling error
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //  recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalLineDecorator(2));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        api = ServiceGenerator.createService(API.class);
        load(0);
        return rootView;
    }
    // load data first time
    private void load(int index) {
        Call<List<Customer>> call = api.getCustomer(index);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Customer>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Customer>> call, final Response<List<Customer>> response) {
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tost "+response.body().get(0).post_writer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Log.i("TRUE_TRUE_","Yes "+response.body().get(2).name);
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    //Log.i("TRUE_TRUE3","Yes"+response.body().toString());
                    //movies.addAll(response.body());
                    //adapter.notifyDataChanged();
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                     // No.1 ..............
                     // ShowDataScreen();
                     // Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "ShowDataScreen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     //if(customers.get()){
                     customers.addAll(response.body());
                     adapter.notifyDataChanged();
                     initiUserlock(customers.size());
                        }
                    });// end of No.1 UI new thread
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {//No.2
                            // Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "This is correct way",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });// end of No.2 UI new thread
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tost "+response.body().get(0).post_writer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, " Response Error " + String.valueOf(response.code()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Customer>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, " Response Error " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    //  laod more data ...................................
    private void loadMore(int index) {
        // add loading progress view ....
        //Toast.makeText(context, "loadMore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        customers.add(new Customer("load"));
        // customers.get(index).user_id =2;
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(customers.size() - 1);
        Call<List<Customer>> call = api.getCustomer(index);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Customer>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Customer>> call, Response<List<Customer>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "it is Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    customers.remove(customers.size() - 1);
                    List<Customer> result = response.body();
                   // Log.i("Getresult{--: ", " "+result.get());
                    if(result.size()>0) {
                      customers.addAll(result);
                      //add loaded data


                        // How to delete every item = 3 from  customers list
                        for (int i=0; i<customers.size(); i++) {
                            if(customers.get(i).user_id == 3){
                             //  customers.remove(i);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        //result size 0 means there is no more data available at server
                        adapter.setMoreDataAvailable(false);
                        //telling adapter to stop calling load more as no more server data available
                        Toast.makeText(context,"لايوجد بيانات اخرى", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    adapter.notifyDataChanged();
                    //should call the custom method adapter.notifyDataChanged here to get the correct loading status
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, " Load More Response Error000 " + String.valueOf(response.code()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Customer>> call,Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, " Load More Response Error_11 " + t.getMessage());
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Fetch the value of element and check whether it contains 3 or not. Do it inside adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have the new list in the result list, you can solve it by using the result List and add it to the customers List

```
customers.clear();
for(Customer newCustomer: result){
   if(newCustomer.user_id != 3){
       customers.add(newCustomer);
   }
}
```

Second option would be to iterate over the customers list using **ListIterator**

```
ListIterator<Customer> iter = customers.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(iter.next().user_id == 3){
         iter.remove();
     }
}
```

Or

```
customers.removeIf(customer -> customer.user_id == 3);
```

Comment: I tried to use the first loop that you wrote, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: I'm still trying to make the function work, but I find duplicate values after that.

Comment: In duplicate values, do you mean that after running the loop (debug), the customers List still includes elements with user_id == 3?